# CDATA does not work as expected

Tags: php, html, cdata

I wrote a function :

```js
function wrapWithTag($tag, $data) {
  $cdata = "<![CDATA[$data]]>";
  echo "<$tag>$cdata</$tag>";
}
```

For instance I like to use it as

```js
$name = 'myCellContent - <extra>';
wrapWithTag("td", $name);
```

The expected output would be a html table cell with string:

```html
myCellContent - <extra>
```

What it actually does is printing empty cells. How can I use CDATA properly?

**Edit**: I have got a simple workaround:

```js
function wrapWithTag($tag, $data) {
  $data = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $data);
  echo "<$tag>$data</$tag>";
}
```

However, I would prefer using a CDATA section. Feel free to post a solution :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CDATA sections](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-cdata-sect) are a feature of XML. HTML does not support them.

XHTML does, but you must ensure the browser is parsing the document in XML mode (by setting `Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml` in the HTTP response headers).

In HTML, if you want to use characters which have special meaning, you must use entities such as `&lt;`.

PHP has [the `htmlspecialchars` function](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars); there's no need to roll your own with `str_replace`.